# Build a filter form for a list in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a form with 6 fields for filtering an array list in PHP.

On form submit I want the filter to be applied on the list and only show entries that matches the input of the 6 fields.

I use filter_array(), but need some code to apply all filters.

Can anyone help me?

I managed to apply the first field using an If-statement, but as soon as I apply the second field, the list now includes entries that doesn't fullfill the first filter.

My array looks like this

```
$o[] = array ('Sagsnummer' =>31400, 'Prod.ordrenummer' => 0101, 'Status' => "Ordre", 'Fase' => "Produktion", 'Projektleder' => "RALF", 'Montageleder' => "JALU");
$o[] = array ('Sagsnummer' =>31400, 'Prod.ordrenummer' => 0102, 'Status' => "Ordre", 'Fase' => "Produktion", 'Projektleder' => "RALF", 'Montageleder' => "JALU");
$o[] = array ('Sagsnummer' =>31400, 'Prod.ordrenummer' => 0103, 'Status' => "Ordre", 'Fase' => "Produktion", 'Projektleder' => "RALF", 'Montageleder' => "JALU");
$o[] = array ('Sagsnummer' =>35683, 'Prod.ordrenummer' => 0101, 'Status' => "Ordre", 'Fase' => "Produktion", 'Projektleder' => "EHA", 'Montageleder' => "DEKA");
$o[] = array ('Sagsnummer' =>35683, 'Prod.ordrenummer' => 0102, 'Status' => "Ordre", 'Fase' => "Produktion", 'Projektleder' => "EHA", 'Montageleder' => "DEKA");
$o[] = array ('Sagsnummer' =>35683, 'Prod.ordrenummer' => 0103, 'Status' => "Ordre", 'Fase' => "Produktion", 'Projektleder' => "EHA", 'Montageleder' => "DEKA");
$o[] = array ('Sagsnummer' =>36180, 'Prod.ordrenummer' => 0101, 'Status' => "Ordre", 'Fase' => "Produktion", 'Projektleder' => "EHA", 'Montageleder' => "JALU");
$o[] = array ('Sagsnummer' =>36193, 'Prod.ordrenummer' => 0101, 'Status' => "Ordre", 'Fase' => "Produktion", 'Projektleder' => "MKJE", 'Montageleder' => "HJHS");
$o[] = array ('Sagsnummer' =>31400, 'Prod.ordrenummer' => 0104, 'Status' => "Ordre", 'Fase' => "Produktion", 'Projektleder' => "RALF", 'Montageleder' => "JALU");
$o[] = array ('Sagsnummer' =>31400, 'Prod.ordrenummer' => 0105, 'Status' => "Ordre", 'Fase' => "Produktion", 'Projektleder' => "RALF", 'Montageleder' => "JALU");
$o[] = array ('Sagsnummer' =>31400, 'Prod.ordrenummer' => 0106, 'Status' => "Ordre", 'Fase' => "Produktion", 'Projektleder' => "RALF", 'Montageleder' => "JALU");
$o[] = array ('Sagsnummer' =>36193, 'Prod.ordrenummer' => 0102, 'Status' => "Ordre", 'Fase' => "Produktion", 'Projektleder' => "MKJE", 'Montageleder' => "HJHS");
```

The filter fields is named

```
$fsagsnr;
$forside;
$status;
$fase;
$fprojektleder;
$fmontageleder;
```

I call filter_array() with

```
$new_array = array_filter($o, array(new Filter($fsagsnr, $forside, $status, $fase, $fprojektleder), 'filter'));
```

And my Filter class looks like this

```
class Filter {
  private $sagsnr;
  private $forside;
  private $status;
  private $fase;
  private $projektleder;

  function __construct($sn,$fo,$st,$fa,$pl) {
    $this->sagsnr = $sn;
    $this->forside = $fo;
    $this->status = $st;
    $this->fase = $fa;
    $this->projektleder = $pl;
  }

  function filter($i) {
    $result = false;
    if($this->sagsnr != "" && ($i["Sagsnummer"] == $this->sagsnr)) $result = true;
    elseif($this->forside != "" && ($i["Prod.ordrenummer"] == $this->forside)) $result = true;
    return $result;
  }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

I now only have one If-statement in my filter function.

```
if(($this->sagsnr == "" || $i["Sagsnummer"] == $this->sagsnr) && ($this->forside == "" || $i["Prod.ordrenummer"] == $this->forside) && ($this->status == "" || $i["Status"] == $this->status) && ($this->fase == "" || $i["Fase"] == $this->fase) && ($this->projektleder == "" || $i["Projektleder"] == $this->projektleder) && ($this->montageleder == "" || $i["Montageleder"] == $this->montageleder)) $result = true;
```

Comment: Well if you want to apply all conditions at the same time … then _do_ that, instead of returning something after the first one is true already?

Comment: @04FS can you provide me with a code-snippet?

Comment: Join the individual conditions together using a logical AND, and then assign the value of $result based on that. But you will need to take care of the cases where a search value was not provided individually each time - so your first condition would become `$this->sagsnr == "" || ($this->sagsnr != "" && ($i["Sagsnummer"] == $this->sagsnr))` to cover both those cases. Do that for all of them, and join them with && (and don’t forget to put grouping braces around each set.)

Comment: (That could be condensed to `$this->sagsnr == "" || $i["Sagsnummer"] == $this->sagsnr` though, because PHP will only evaluate the second part of the ||-joined conditions if the first one was false to begin with.)

Comment: Great! I cobbled the comments together into an answer, so you have something to accept and thereby mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

> I managed to apply the first field using an If-statement, but as soon as I apply the second field, the list now includes entries that doesn't fullfill the first filter.

That’s because if that first check results in “true”, it doesn’t go into any else/else-if branches.

You need to check all of your conditions in one go, not as alternatives to each other.

Join the individual conditions together using a logical AND, and then assign the value of $result based on that. But you will need to take care of the cases where a search value was not provided individually each time - so your first condition would become

```
$this->sagsnr == "" || ($this->sagsnr != "" && ($i["Sagsnummer"] == $this->sagsnr))
```

to cover both those cases. Do that for all of them, and join them with && – and don’t forget to put grouping braces around each set.

(That could be condensed to `$this->sagsnr == "" || $i["Sagsnummer"] == $this->sagsnr` though, because PHP will only evaluate the second part of the `||`-joined conditions if the first one was false to begin with.)